# issues with Clock function C

Tags: c99

I am having a issue with the clock function. There is an array passed to the function and we are supposed to measure the time it takes to search. I am also doing this with sort functions and it seems to work without a problem. The array passed is presorted.

I am getting results of 0.0000 and -1.9500 as results. The print f for time match. I am reusing this in other functions as the program measures time for 3 sorts, 2 searches, for arrays varying from 10 to 20000 numbers.

```
// linear search from book
 void linearSearch(int *list, int size, int key) // int key taken out
 {
    //returns the location of key in the list
    // a-1 is returned if value is not found
    int index, found, i;
    clock_t t6 = 0;
    clock_t t7 = 0;
    clock_t diff =0;
    double timefin;
    //float diff;

    index = -1;
    found = FALSE;
    i = 0;
    t6 = clock();
    while (i < size && !found)
    {
            if (list[i] == key)
            {
                    found = TRUE;
                    index = i;
            }
            i++; //Move to the next item
    }
    t7 =clock(); 
    diff =t7 - t6;
 printf("\nt6: %f", (float)t6);
 printf("\nt7: %f", (float)t7);
    //diff = (((float)t7 - (float)t6) / 1000000.0F );  

    printf("\nThe Linear search for %d took %.4f seconds",key, (float)diff); 
  //  return(index);
}
```

full code, using GDB to compile and run on Ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE  0
#define randScope 20000



// random number generator
void randNum(int *num, int sizeNum, int maxRand)
{
    int i;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    for(i=0; i<sizeNum; i++)
    num[i]= rand() % maxRand;
    //return 0;
}

int randOneNum(int maxRand)
{
    int num;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    num= rand() % maxRand;
    return num;
}

// bubble sort from book
int bubbleSort(int *num, int sizeSort)
{
    int i, j, temp, moves =0;
    clock_t t0 = 0;
    clock_t t1 = 0;
    double timefin;
    clock_t diff;


//      for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//      printf ("\nStart Numbers %d", num[i]);

    t0 = clock();  

    for(i =0; i < (sizeSort -1); i++)
    {
            for(j =0; j < (sizeSort -1); j++)
            {
                    if (num[j] < num [j-1])
                    {
                            temp = num[j];
                            num[j] = num[j-1];
                            num[j-1] = temp;
                            moves++;
                    }
            }
    }
    t1 = clock();
    diff = t1-t0; 
    printf("\nt0: %f", (float)t0);
    //diff = (((float)t1 - (float)t0) / 1000000.0F );  
//      for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//      printf ("\nSorted numbers %d", num[i]);

    printf("\nThe Bubble sort for %d numbers took %.4f seconds",sizeSort, (float)diff);

    return (moves);
}



// selection sort from book
int selectionSort(int *num,  int sizeSort)
{
    int i,j, min, minidx, temp,moves = 0;
    clock_t t2 = 0;
    clock_t t3 = 0;
    double timefin;
    clock_t diff;


//      for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//      printf ("\nStart Numbers %d", num[i]);

    t2 = clock();  

    for(i =0; i < (sizeSort -1); i++)
    {
            min = num[i]; /* assume minimum is first element in the sublist */
            minidx=i; /*index*/
            for(j=i+1; j<sizeSort; j++)
            {
                    if (num[j] < min) /* lower value found capture it */
                    {
                            min = num[j];
                            minidx =j;
                    }
            }
            if (min < num[i]) /* check if we have a new min if so swap values*/
            {
                    temp = num[i];
                    num[i] = min;
                    num[minidx] = temp;
                    moves++;
            }
    }
    t3 = clock();
    diff = t3-t2;
printf("\nt2: %f", (float)t2);


    //diff = (((float)t3 - (float)t2) / 1000000.0F );  
//      for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//      printf ("\nSorted numbers %d", num[i]);

    printf("\nThe Selection sort for %d numbers took %.4f seconds",sizeSort,     (float)diff);
    return (moves);
}


//insertion sort from Rostetta code http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort#C
static void insertion_sort(int *num, int sizeSort)
{
int i, j, value;
    clock_t t4 = 0;
    clock_t t5 = 0;
double timefin;
clock_t diff;


//  for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//  printf ("\nStart Numbers %d", num[i]);

t4 = clock();

for (i = 1; i < sizeSort; i++) {
    value = num[i];
    for (j = i; j > 0 && value < num[j - 1]; j--) {
        num[j] = num[j - 1];
    }
    num[j] = value;
}
t5 = clock();  
diff = t5-t4;
printf("\nt4: %f", (float)t4);


//diff = (((float)t5 - (float)t4) / 1000000.0F );  
//  for(i =0; i < 3; i++)
//  printf ("\nSorted numbers %d", num[i]);

printf("\nThe Insertion sort for %d numbers took %.4f seconds",sizeSort, (float)diff);
}

// linear search from book
void linearSearch(int *list, int size, int key) // int key taken out
{
    //returns the location of key in the list
    // a-1 is returned if value is not found
    int index, found, i;
    clock_t t6 = 0;
    clock_t t7 = 0;
    clock_t diff =0;
    double timefin;
    //float diff;

    index = -1;
    found = FALSE;
    i = 0;
    t6 = clock();
    while (i < size && !found)
    {
            if (list[i] == key)
            {
                    found = TRUE;
                    index = i;
            }
            i++; //Move to the next item
    }
    t7 =clock();
    diff =t7 - t6;
printf("\nt6: %f", (float)t6);
printf("\nt7: %f", (float)t7);
    //diff = (((float)t7 - (float)t6) / 1000000.0F ); 

    printf("\nThe Linear search for %d took %.4f seconds",key, (float)diff);
  //  return(index);
}

// binary search from book
void binarySearch(int *list, int size, int key) // int key taken out
{
    // returns the locations of key in the list if a-1 is returned the value is not found
    int index, found, left,right, midpt;
    clock_t t8 = 0;
    clock_t t9 = 0;
    clock_t start,end;
    struct tms st_cpu;
    struct tms end_cpu;
    double timefin;
    clock_t diff;

    index = -1;
    found = FALSE;
    left = 0;
    right = size-1;

    t8 = clock(); 

    while(left <= right && !found)
    {
            midpt = (int) ((left + right) /2);
            if (key == list[midpt])
            {
                    found = TRUE;
                    index = midpt;
            }
            else if (key > list[midpt])
                    left = midpt + 1;
            else
                    right = midpt -1;
    }
    t9 = clock();  
    diff = t9-t8;

printf("\nt8: %f", (float)t8);

    //diff = (((float)t9 - (float)t8) / 1000000.0F );  
    printf("\nThe Binary search for %d took %.4f seconds",key, (float)diff);
   // return index;
}


void main()
{

//  insertion_sort(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
//10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000

int i;
int key[9];
// Bubble Sort Arrays
int numB10[10];
int numB50[50];
int numB100[100];
int numB500[500];
int numB1000[1000];
int numB5000[5000];
int numB10000[10000];
int numB15000[15000];
int numB20000[20000];




// Selection Sort Arrays
int numS10[10];
int numS50[50];
int numS100[100];
int numS500[500];
int numS1000[1000];
int numS5000[5000];
int numS10000[10000];
int numS15000[15000];
int numS20000[20000];

// Insertion Sort Arrays
int numI10[10];
int numI50[50];
int numI100[100];
int numI500[500];
int numI1000[1000];
int numI5000[5000];
int numI10000[10000];
int numI15000[15000];
int numI20000[20000];

// initialize random array
randNum(numB10000, 10000, 20000);

// Initialize keys for search
key[0]=numB10000[randOneNum(10)];
key[1]=numB10000[randOneNum(50)];
key[2]=numB10000[randOneNum(100)];
key[3]=numB10000[randOneNum(500)];
key[4]=numB10000[randOneNum(1000)];
key[5]=numB10000[randOneNum(5000)];
key[6]=numB10000[randOneNum(10000)];
key[7]=numB10000[randOneNum(15000)];
key[8]=numB10000[randOneNum(20000)];


// Copy array to size 10 arrays
memcpy(numI10, numB10000, 10*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS10, numB10000, 10*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB10, numB10000, 10*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 50 arrays
memcpy(numI50, numB10000, 50*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS50, numB10000, 50*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB50, numB10000, 50*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 100 arrays
memcpy(numI100, numB10000, 100*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS100, numB10000, 100*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB100, numB10000, 100*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 500 arrays
memcpy(numI500, numB10000, 500*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS500, numB10000, 500*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB500, numB10000, 500*sizeof(int));


// Copy array to size 1000 arrays
memcpy(numI1000, numB10000, 1000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS1000, numB10000, 1000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB1000, numB10000, 1000*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 5000 arrays
memcpy(numI5000, numB10000, 5000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS5000, numB10000, 5000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB5000, numB10000, 5000*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 10000 arrays
memcpy(numI10000, numB10000, 10000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS10000, numB10000, 10000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB10000, numB10000, 10000*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 15000 arrays
memcpy(numI15000, numB20000, 15000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS15000, numB20000, 15000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numB15000, numB20000, 15000*sizeof(int));

// Copy array to size 20000 arrays
memcpy(numI20000, numB20000, 20000*sizeof(int));
memcpy(numS20000, numB20000, 20000*sizeof(int));

//10
selectionSort(numS10, 10);
bubbleSort(numB10, 10);
insertion_sort(numI10, 10);
linearSearch(numI10, 10, key[0]);
binarySearch(numI10, 10, key[0]);

printf("\n");
//50
selectionSort(numS50, 50);
bubbleSort(numB50, 50);
insertion_sort(numI50, 50);
linearSearch(numI50, 50, key[1]);
binarySearch(numI50, 50, key[1]);

printf("\n");  
//100
selectionSort(numS100, 100);
bubbleSort(numB100, 100);
insertion_sort(numI100, 100);
linearSearch(numI100, 100, key[2]);
binarySearch(numI100, 100, key[2]);

printf("\n");
//500
selectionSort(numS500, 500);
bubbleSort(numB500, 500);
insertion_sort(numI500, 500);
linearSearch(numI500, 500, key[3]);
binarySearch(numI500, 500, key[3]);

printf("\n");
//1000
selectionSort(numS1000, 1000);
bubbleSort(numB1000, 1000);
insertion_sort(numI1000, 1000);
linearSearch(numI1000, 1000, key[4]);
binarySearch(numI1000, 1000, key[4]);

printf("\n");
//5000
selectionSort(numS5000, 5000);
bubbleSort(numB5000, 5000);
insertion_sort(numI5000, 5000);
linearSearch(numI5000, 5000, key[5]);
binarySearch(numI5000, 5000, key[5]);


printf("\n");
//10000
selectionSort(numS10000, 10000);
bubbleSort(numB10000, 10000);
insertion_sort(numI10000, 10000);
linearSearch(numI10000, 10000, key[6]);
binarySearch(numI10000, 10000, key[6]);

printf("\n");
//15000
selectionSort(numS15000, 15000);
bubbleSort(numB15000, 15000);
insertion_sort(numI15000, 15000);
linearSearch(numI15000, 15000, key[7]);
binarySearch(numI15000, 15000, key[7]);

printf("\n");
//20000
selectionSort(numS20000, 20000);
bubbleSort(numB20000, 20000);
insertion_sort(numI20000, 20000);
linearSearch(numI20000, 20000, key[8]);
binarySearch(numI20000, 20000, key[8]);

}
```

Here is the output I'm receiving.

```
t2: 0.000000
The Selection sort for 10 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t0: 0.000000
The Bubble sort for 10 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t4: 0.000000
The Insertion sort for 10 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 0.000000
t7: 0.000000
The Linear search for 1781 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 0.000000
The Binary search for 1781 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 0.000000
The Selection sort for 50 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t0: 0.000000
The Bubble sort for 50 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t4: 0.000000
The Insertion sort for 50 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 0.000000
t7: 0.000000
The Linear search for 1744 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 0.000000
The Binary search for 1744 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 0.000000
The Selection sort for 100 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t0: 0.000000
The Bubble sort for 100 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t4: 0.000000
The Insertion sort for 100 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 0.000000
t7: 0.000000
The Linear search for 1744 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 0.000000
The Binary search for 1744 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 0.000000
The Selection sort for 500 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t0: 0.000000
The Bubble sort for 500 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t4: 0.000000
The Insertion sort for 500 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 0.000000
t7: 0.000000
The Linear search for 17032 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 0.000000
The Binary search for 17032 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 0.000000
The Selection sort for 1000 numbers took 10000.0000 seconds
t0: 10000.000000
The Bubble sort for 1000 numbers took 10000.0000 seconds
t4: 20000.000000
The Insertion sort for 1000 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 20000.000000
t7: 20000.000000
The Linear search for 8704 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 20000.000000
The Binary search for 8704 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 20000.000000
The Selection sort for 5000 numbers took 110000.0000 seconds
t0: 130000.000000
The Bubble sort for 5000 numbers took 400000.0000 seconds
t4: 530000.000000
The Insertion sort for 5000 numbers took 80000.0000 seconds
t6: 610000.000000
t7: 610000.000000
The Linear search for 17877 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 610000.000000
The Binary search for 17877 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 610000.000000
The Selection sort for 10000 numbers took 430000.0000 seconds
t0: 1040000.000000
The Bubble sort for 10000 numbers took 1600000.0000 seconds
t4: 2640000.000000
The Insertion sort for 10000 numbers took 330000.0000 seconds
t6: 2970000.000000
t7: 2970000.000000
The Linear search for 3961 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 2970000.000000
The Binary search for 3961 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 2970000.000000
The Selection sort for 15000 numbers took 970000.0000 seconds
t0: 3940000.000000
The Bubble sort for 15000 numbers took 2950000.0000 seconds
t4: 6890000.000000
The Insertion sort for 15000 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 6890000.000000
t7: 6890000.000000
The Linear search for 17877 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 6890000.000000
The Binary search for 17877 took 0.0000 seconds

t2: 6890000.000000
The Selection sort for 20000 numbers took 1760000.0000 seconds
t0: 8650000.000000
The Bubble sort for 20000 numbers took 5790000.0000 seconds
t4: 14440000.000000
The Insertion sort for 20000 numbers took 0.0000 seconds
t6: 14440000.000000
t7: 14440000.000000
The Linear search for 1074 took 0.0000 seconds
t8: 14440000.000000
The Binary search for 1074 took 0.0000 seconds
```

Comment: Ok spoke with teacher, haven't tested it yet, but we believe the compiler is optimizing the code, running things concurrently and thus coming up with the fast searches and weird timings. Going to try and par this down to a user entered array size and do one at a time for the lists of searches and sorts

Comment: Note that PC's are *very* fast at doing this, I just ran your linear search through 100,000 int's Total time: 52uS - that's 0.000052 of a second (or 0.00000000052sec per loop !) on a 3GHz i7 windows PC

Answer (score 1):

See this for a description of clock(): http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm

Since the clock_t is in ticks (which are defined by CLOCKS_PER_SEC), your code probably executes in less than a single tick. Try increasing the sort/searches or put the code in a loop and do it, say 10,000 times.

Comment: as this is for an assignment with the sizes of the arrays defined, I can't really do that, meeting with teacher today in Office hours to see about solution, thanks!